# Is power-associativity an equational property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, systems-of-equations, associativity, magma

A magma $M$ is said to be power-associative if the subalgebra generated by any element is associative. This can be written simply as $x^mx^n=x^{m+n}$ for all $m,n$ positive integers and $x\in M$, where $x^m$ is defined recursively via $x^1=x$, $x^{n+1}=x^nx$.

This specification requires an infinite set of equations, one for each $m,n$. Is there a way to write the constraint of power-associativity using only a finite number of formulas involving variables in $M$? My guess is no, but how to prove it?

Comment: If you allow $\forall$ into your expression, then it is very possible to write the whole condition in one line. But yes, you technically have to check infinitely many equations, hopefully through some general argument that covers many at a time. What such an argument might look like it's entirely dependent of what magma you have.

Comment: @Arthur You need more than just forall, you need quantification over $\Bbb N$ or some other inductive set.

Comment: I meant that you need "$\forall n,m\in \Bbb N,x\in M$", yes.

Comment: @Arthur Right. I believe there is a quantifiable way in which this is considered more "complex" than if you only allow quantification over $M$ itself, as a first order theory.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362369/is-the-class-of-power-associative-binars-finitely-axiomatizable which, after you ignore all the irrelevant discussion about how to call things and so on, answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

This is a reformulation of [the answer of YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/a/362375/34444) on MO in more elementary terms and with some details filled in.

Suppose that there is a finite set $R$ of relations which generates exactly the power-associative magmas. Because each such relation is derivable from $\{x^mx^n=x^{m+n}\mid m,n\in\Bbb N\}$, by compactness there is an $N>1$ such that all relations in $R$ are derivable from $\{x^mx^n=x^{m+n}\mid m+n\le N\}$. Therefore without loss of generality we can take our finite set of relations to be $\{x^mx^n=x^{m+n}\mid m+n\le N\}$.

Now we claim that $xx^N=a$ is provable only if $a$ has the form $xb$ where $b$ contains $N$ occurrences of $x$. To see this, note that we can only rewrite $xb$ by rewriting $b$ (which yields $xb'$ where $b'$ also has $N$ $x$'s because the relations preserve the number of $x$'s), rewriting $x$ (impossible because all relations in the set contain at least two $x$'s), or rewriting $xb$ itself (which, except for the trivial relation $xx=xx$, would require $b=x^n$ where $1+n\le N$ which is impossible).

Thus in particular $xx^N=x^Nx$ is not provable, even though it is true in all power-associative magmas, which is a contradiction.